# Prevent Windows 10 from using Microsoft Account

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-account

Every time I start Internet Explorer to accommodate for a poorly programmed IP camera's web admin interface, Windows 10 tells me that it wants to fix my Microsoft Account (probably because of a changed password). I do not use a Microsoft Account nor do I wish for Windows to constantly attempt to do so.

How do I turn off any and all attempts to use Microsoft Account in Windows 10?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please include a screenshot of the message.

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of `Settings -> Accounts` remove your private information from the screenshot before submitting the edit to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Start, Settings, Accounts, select your Microsoft Account to a Local Account. You will have to use the Forgot Password to reset the password first, but then change to a Local Account. That works for Windows, but does not affect Office Subscription if you have it. It may be your Office Subscription causing the message.

If you had a Microsoft Account and changed that account to Local (you can do that), Microsoft may have a memory of the Microsoft Account. When the message comes up, see if there is a "Forgot Password" facility for you to use.

Comment: I am logging into the computer with a local account. I am not using a Microsoft Account.

Comment: It only asks you to fix a Microsoft Account if you have one. Look in Computer, right click, Manage, Users a Groups for all your accounts. It would seem that there must be a Microsoft Account on your computer

Comment: Right-click `This Computer` - `Manage` takes me to `compmgmt.msc`, which has an item called `Local Users and Groups`. That item has the built-in accounts, my local user account and the user account used by the backup software. Under `Manage your account`, I can see the name of my account and the words `Local Account` underneath the account name. Under `Email & accounts`, which is to be found on the side, there is a setting `Accounts used by other apps`, which contains my Skype account name. That is pre-Microsoft. Logging into Skype produces no problems. I do not have a Microsoft Account.

Comment: As you were asked above, edit your question and post a screen shot of the complete message you see. It may be your Office Account.

Comment: I will happily do so in a while. Meanwhile, I am not using Office as a subscription product nor do I have an Office account.

Comment: The message is this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7Pls.png. Right now it is having a demo effect, which means it refuses to pop up, and I had to copy the message from the Web. However, the triggering factor for this is when I start Internet Explorer (which I normally do once in a week), possibly Skype and possibly Teams.

Comment: That is most definitely a Microsoft Account from your computer. Log into this Microsoft Site and see if you can create a password and deal with it. You must have had a Microsoft Account at some point:  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4028195/microsoft-account-how-to-sign-in

Comment: Correct. I did have a Microsoft Account at some point. The culprit is Skype. However, I am not using a Microsoft Account to the best of my knowledge. Starting a Microsoft program may trigger the notice but, as fate would have it, not for this specific case. I can remove the Microsoft Account from `Email & accounts`, and it will reappear the moment I start Skype. However, I have changed the password to the account with Firefox, which renders Windows unaware of the new password. Thence the bugging when I start a Microsoft program. The question is: how do I prevent Windows from even trying?

Comment: The Microsoft site you are suggesting suggests a way for me to log in with a Microsoft Account. The goal is to get rid of the Microsoft Account, not log in with it.

Comment: If you can log in there, you may be able to cancel it. That was the point of going there. There must have been a Microsoft Account at one point. I have one (of 3) machines here that never had a Microsoft Account - just Local (since new in 2016).  It never asks me about my Microsoft Account. The other two do ask occasionally

Comment: I am happy to delete my answer by the way. All the comments below it will go as well. But say the word and I will delete it.

Comment: Keep the answer. Someone else may benefit from it. My case will not. I know that I could get rid of the notices by simply telling Windows what the password to the Microsoft Account (which Skype apparently uses) is but that would then make it possible for Windows to log into that account without telling me, and I do not want that, either.